# Como ler um XML que está dentro do projeto?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-core, asp

Estou criando uma aplicação web com o `.NET Core Razor` e estou precisando fazer com que o meu código leia um arquivo `XML`. Eu já consigo fazer com que ele leia este `XML`, mas com outro caminho, que está fora do meu projeto. Ou seja, se outra pessoa for executar o meu código, precisará ter o mesmo caminho do `XML` que eu estou usando, oque não fica prático. Se eu conseguir fazer com que ele seja lido dentro do próprio projeto, o problema está resolvido.

Bom, eu estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Dados\VS\MenuXML\menuV11.Xml");
```

Está funcionando. Mas este não é o caminho que eu estou procurando.

O meu projeto tem esta estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então eu gostaria que ele lesse a partir deste `XML` que deixei aberto, no caminho que seria

> wwwroot > MenuXML > menuV11.Xml

Eu tentei das seguintes formas:

```
var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("~/MenuXML/menuV11");
var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"~/MenuXML/menuV11");
var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("~/MenuXML/menuV11.Xml");
var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"~/MenuXML/menuV11.Xml");
```

Mas não obtive bons resultados. Todas deram erro. Conto com a ajuda de vocês. Obrigado.

Comment: @Maniero, qual o problema com a questão? Deixei claro que quero ler o arquivo xml e mostrei o caminho que ele está. Só não sei com fazer.

Comment: Acho que faltou o "wwwroot" `var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"wwwroot\MenuXML\menuV11.xml");`

Comment: @Barbetta, na minha página de layout, eu uso `~` para referenciar o `wwwroot`. Funcionou oque você me passou, mas sabe o motivo de não ter funcionado aqui com o `~`?

Comment: Nunca parei para pensar o motivo rsrs, vou pesquisar, se achar algo te aviso.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2 Leitura interessante sobre o assunto.

Comment: A versão original não tinha tudo isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário informar a pasta wwwroot no caminho para que de certo., seu código deveria ser assim:

```
var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"wwwroot\MenuXML\menuV11.xml");
```

Aproveito para deixar um link que fala sobre arquivos estáticos, talvez ajude em algo:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2